# Comparison with && and || not working

Tags: php, comparison, operators, logical-operators

This first comparison will check if the value is 14 in length and the User ID is `1`

```
if ($checkValueLenght === 14 && $UserID[0] === "1") { code... }
```

but I want it to check if it is 1 or 2, and I cant get this to work ...

```
if ($checkValueLenght === 14 && $UserID[0] === "1" || "2") { code... }
```

it goes trough the code whatever letter or number the UserID starts with, but not if it is not exactly 14 in length. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please refer to a manual.

Comment: You can't just use `||` to compare a variable against multiple values. What you wrote is basically: `if ( ($checkValueLenght === 14) && ($UserID[0] === "1") || ("2") ) { code... }` Make sense now?

Comment: An alternative is phps `in_array()` function.

Comment: This did not work for me, same result as in my code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this ...

```
if ($checkValueLenght === 14 && ($UserID[0] === "1" || $UserID[0] === "2")) { code... }
```

or better, this ...

```
if ($checkValueLenght === 14 && in_array($UserID[0],["1","2"]) { code... }
```

assuming that the value of `$UserID[0]` is indeed a string.

Comment: This did work! Thank you very much!

Comment: @user3771408 Excellent. If you want you can accept an answer by clicking the tick next to it. There is no obligation to do so, but both you and the answerer will gain some rep points.